# I Cant apply my masterpage in office 365

Tags: design-manager

I am a sharepoint newbie, I just converted my html page to a masterpage in office 365 but when I go to Site Settings > Master Pages ....in order to apply my master page to the site, I cant find my converted masterpage in the dropdown, I have been on this for a while now, Please I need your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to Site Settings>Design Manager>Edit Master Pages and make sure the master page is published.

Look at the Approval Status column.  If it says Draft then your master page is not published yet.  Publish a major version and the status will change to Approved.

To publish a major version click the ellipsis (...) then click it again in the pop-up window and then click Publish a Major Version.  Add comments if desired.  Click OK.  The Approval Status should change to Approved.

If you still can't see the pages might double check to make sure the Publishing Feature is turned on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great.  Glad you got it all sorted.